# Can't find data folder of an installed game

Tags: file-management

I've installed a game through Google Play and I would like to analyze data files to see where information about progress are stored, but I can't find any folder of the game itself.

In `sdcard/Android/data` there is no game folder. Wehre should I look?

Answer (score 3):

Applications keep their data in `/data/data`. It is a folder that resides in a partition that a normal user can't access. In order to access there, you have to root your phone and download another file explorer application that can browse `/data`.

I'd personally suggest [Nextapp FX File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx&hl=tr) with [Root Add-On](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx.rr) or [ES File Explorer.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

Comment: I think Root Explorer is the best root file explorer

Answer (score 0):

You need to root your device.

Download an Root File Manager, im using Xplore File Manager but you can download Root Explorer app.
Goto /data/data/ (package name of the app) / (whole data)
Note: you need to root your device.

Answer (score 0):

If u don't have root for this phone one possible work around is that you can back up the game using phone's built-in backup app. Then u may unpack the backed up file. Or just recover the backup to someone else's rooted phone, or an emulator.